# Registered models do not show up in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I added a model to admin via `admin.site.register`, and it does not show up in admin. Since admin is so "It just works", I have no idea of how to debug this. Pointers?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After adding and registering your admin:

```
# app/admin.py
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

Make sure your app is in your project `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # other apps ...
    'app',
)
```

Sync your project for that model if you have not done so already:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Restart your server, `CTRL-C`:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: That's a good summary! It solves 90% of the issue with models not displaying in admin! +1

Comment: For me, `python manage.py runserver` didn't work because I was testing using a live server on port 80, so I had to enter the command `sudo service apache2 restart` and it updated the models I recently added to the admin website.

Comment: django's `syncdb` is now deprecated since 1.7, use `python3 manage.py migrate` instead for newer versions of django

Answer (score 13):

In such a situation is also a good practice to check if the user logged in to the admin panel has rights to manage such a model. If they do then you could change your code to access the functions as  root.

Comment: how do you check that? how do you grant your user rights on a specific model?

Answer (score 8):

When in doubt, shut down server, syncdb, start server.

Comment: Definite +1 for this comment. I thought the development server would pick up any changes in admin.py files - couldn't guarantee that 100%

Restarting the server made a world of difference (in a positive way).

Comment: Changes yes, but development server doesn't pick up new files.

Comment: I tend to always have my settings.py file open and a quick hack to reboot the server is to modify the settings file, which causes the Dev server to pick up any new changes.

Comment: an extra tip: after shutting down the server, delete all pyc files!

Comment: Just restarting the server made the admin 'view' the registered models. Didn't need to migrate, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I have the experience, that sometimes after changing an admin.py the dev-sever won't be restarted. in that case `touch settings.py` helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think the checklist in Thierry's answer is almost definitive, but make sure that `urls.py` contains `admin.autodiscover()` to load `INSTALLED_APPS` admin.py modules.

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

More info in the [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf).

Comment: As of Django 1.7, `admin.autodiscover()` [is no longer required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#discovery-of-admin-files)

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the application to your installed apps? That has happened to me both one and two times. :) Otherwise it would be useful for us to see the code to help you.

Comment: This 1,000x!!!! I just spent 2 hours tearing my hair out, going over 3 nearly identical apps, one of which was showing up, and two which weren't. I knew that the Admin site had them registered, as duplicate or invalid registration was throwing and error. Every "beginner" mistake that was cited on SO wasn't at issue. Then buried deep in this thread was your comment, and a facepalm for me. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure there are no syntax errors in your admin.py or anything. That can cause an app to fail to be registered with the AdminSite.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem, but it was a little tricky than yours.

Consider, that you have a project with, say, five or even more apps. For me it is more obvious to register all models in just one admin.py file, so I have decided to do it in one place - core directory. Of course, it was not an app, so none of models showed up on admin page.

Answer (score -1):

comment out the some lines in `urls.py` see docs for more details

```
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```